# How to add data to an object?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I have an API which can accept single data or bulk data and then send the response accordingly. While sending a single data I'm sending the data as below,

```
var contactId = 123;
var url = "www.abc.com";
var companyName = "ABC";
var compLink = "/abc/123/link";
var randomKey = generateRandomKey();

   $.ajax({
       url:liurl,
       type:"POST",
       data:JSON.stringify({
           "verification_key":randomKey,
           "listData" :
               [{
               "contactid":contactId,
               "url": url,
               "li_company":companyName,
               "complink":compLink
           }]
       }),
       contentType:"application/json",
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(result){
           $.each(result, function(index, element) {
               //perform operation on 'result'
           });
       }
   });
```

The above code works perfectly and I get the appropriate response. Now when I want to verify more than 1 record at a time the `listData` should be like this,

```
{
    "verification_key":"d0vvNl04dk3y",
    "listData" :
        [{
        "contactid":"241",
        "url":"http://www.name.com/in/daveandrews",
        "companyName":"Devious Media",
        "complink":"/company/devious-media"
    },
    {
        "contactid":"242",
        "url":"http://www.name.com/in/something",
        "companyName":"Sol Media",
        "complink":"/company/somemedia"
    },{
        "contactid":"243",
        "url":"http://www.name.com/in/daveandrews",
        "companyName":"Mega Media",
        "complink":"/company/xyzmedia"
    }]
}
```

As you can see the `listData` contains details for more than 1 record. and I can't figure out how to couple these multiple data into a single object and send to the API. FYI, the values for `contactid, url, companyName and complink` is stored in an array.
Eg:

```
var contactid = [1,2,3,4,5]
var companyName = ["abc","xyz","qwe","asd","zxc"];
```

Comment: You need to iterate through the first array and use the index of the loop to pull in the correct value from the second (or more) arrays - this is assuming they will always be in perfect order - have a look at this for starters https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: What do you mean by "couple these multiple data into a single object"? Because the important thing is, what does your API expect? I would think that it expects exactly what you're showing in your second code block, but of course, I can't know that.

Comment: Yes, the API accepts the data as shown in the second code block

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something clever, or is it this simple?  I don't think there's a magic functional approach to this, but maybe others are more clever than I am.

Assuming your arrays are the same length, something like this:

```
let listData = [];

for (let i=0; i < contactid.length; i++) {
    listData.push({
        contactid: contactid[i],
        url: "http://www.name.com/in/something",
        li_companyName: companyName[i],
        complink: complink[i]
    });
}
```

(update with how to assemble the new request)

with listData having the correct format, just attach it to your request directly.

```
$.ajax({
   url:liurl,
   type:"POST",
   data:JSON.stringify({
       "verification_key":randomKey,
       "listData" : listData
   }),
   contentType:"application/json",
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(result){
       $.each(result, function(index, element) {
           //perform operation on 'result'
       });
   }
```

});

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm looking for, can you tell me how to add 'verification_key' along with this as shown in my second code block. Keeping in mind that the verification_key will be added only once.